# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

The old question

[Show $1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^N \cos n x = \frac{ \sin (N + 1/2) x }{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$ for $x \neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175768/show-1-2-sum-n-1n-cos-n-x-frac-sin-n-1-2-x-sin-fracx2)

(which has an accepted answer) was edited by a low-rep (<10) user in a way that *completely* changes its intention. Why was this edit approved? If the editing user wants an answer using a different method, they should ask their own question, not hijack someone else's.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. The edit has been rolled back. Flagging the post might be a better way to handle this.

Comment: Dear @robjohn, I did flag the post too. I just wanted to raise it here so that the approvers could explain why they did it.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks :-)

Comment: One irritating thing about the approval of edits process is that unless one is *awfully quick*, an attempt to reject is met with the announcement that the edit has already been approved. Attempts to improve usually meet the same fate.

Comment: I agree with @Andre. It would be great if we can somehow prevent this race condition. (For example if by opening the review you have it assigned to you for some several minutes, unless you press cancel which returns it to the queue.)

Comment: Here is link to [the suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/168405) mentioned in question.

Comment: "I just wanted to raise it here so that the approvers could explain why they did it." Do you have any reason to expect the approvers to read this meta site? And if they do, what exactly do you expect them to give as an explanation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: one of the approvers is a high-rep user who (according to his "about me" text) is quite involved in "administrative" tasks on the site. So I imagine there is a good chance he is also a regular visitor to meta. As for explanation: I don't expect anything, but if someone thinks there is a good reason that I am completely missing to approve this edit, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hopefully the answer isn't "fight robo approval with robo rejection" :)

Comment: @rschwieb: No, I meant that once you open the review dialog the system recognizes that someone is reviewing the edit. So if you don't press "cancel" you have like ten minutes to approve, reject or improve (or cancel) and until that time the system prevents further users from deciding the fate of that review. This will invariably let people read the edits and examine them with leisure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Apparently my off-the-cuff jokes are so unfunny people can find a way to say "no" to them :( I really didn't mean it to address anything about the fix you had in mind... the idea of  robo-rejection just amused me.

Comment: @rschwieb: Robots fighting robots to the death? Bender will not be amused.

Comment: @Asaf it looks this _is_ what happens see [meta stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159514/165400) but not for edits. I wonder why not? (PS I remember being asked to review that edit, I think I tried to reject or skipped on the basis I didn't have the expertise.)

Comment: It happened again here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/688720/8157 . This approved edit changes formatting in such a way that it does not render. It should have been rejected.

Answer (score 11):

> Why was this edit approved?

The reason is more trivial than what we could expect. I wanted to reject, but once we click on "Approve", it seems we can't go back (the opposite problem may not happen because we have to click further on the reason). So it's the last bullet in azimut's answer.

In order to avoid this problem, maybe we could create an option. Each user chooses whether he/she want to have to confirm when he/she approves an edit.

Comment: Dear Davide, thanks for taking the time to explain.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand why Davide was downvoted, when he was kind enough to explain that the approval happened through a simple slip of the mouse.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Probably the downvoter disagrees with my proposal in the last sentences.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like something that could be doable with a user script.  Let me look into it...

Comment: OK, [here's a user script to add an extra confirmation dialog to the "Approve" button.](http://stackapps.com/questions/4567/confirm-review-approval)

Answer (score 7):

I think many unjustified edit approves are provoked by the following causal chain:

- You can earn badges for reviewed edits (Custodian, Proofreader, Reviewer, Steward), making many users keen.
- To achieve a valid edit review, your review must be finished before (typically) two others do. So you have to be fast.
- All users having enough reputation get informed in the status line about waiting edit reviews. So the potential competition is huge and you have to be *very* fast.
- Blindly accepting an edit is much faster than actually thinking about it.

Comment: Dear azimut, I agree with your summary. Sadly, it risks making the edit approval process more or less a waste of time.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Yeah, it's definitely not optimal. I think the situation would be much less fierce if the notification is removed. Also, it doesn't make too much sense that this notification mechanism exists only for the the edit review queue, but not for the other 5 review queues.